# Using this.form.submit() on label tags

Tags: javascript, html, forms

To replicate my problem (using FireFox), please go to [this page](http://goldsovereignexpert.com/year.asp?CoinDate=1887).

If you click the first image, which is a label tag, the form will submit, BUT the value won't be picked-up, so the subsequent page is incorrect.

Hit your back button & click the same image again & you get the correct response.

The same applies on the next page. Click the image label & you'll get a page error. Hit the back button & repeat - this value will be picked-up & the script will continue.

Can anyone explain why this is happening & how I can correct this?

Here's the form that isn't behaving:

```
<form action="lookup.asp" method="post">
<div class="boxes">
  <div class="box">
    <label for="first" onClick="this.form.submit()"> <img src="images/mintmarks/stgeorge-london.png" alt="No mintmark - London"> </label>
    <input value="1" type="radio" name="Mintmark" id="first" onClick="this.form.submit()" checked="checked">
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <label for="third" onClick="this.form.submit()"> <img src="images/mintmarks/stgeorge-melbourne.png" alt="Melbourne mintmark"> </label>
    <input value="3" type="radio" name="Mintmark" id="third" onClick="this.form.submit()">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="boxes">
  <div class="box">
    <label for="second" onClick="this.form.submit()"> <img src="images/mintmarks/stgeorge-sydney.png" alt="Sydney mintmark"> </label>
    <input value="2" type="radio" name="Mintmark" id="second" onClick="this.form.submit()">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="boxes">
  <div class="row">
    <input name="CoinDate" type="hidden" value="1895" />
    <input name="Bust" type="hidden" value="7" />
    <input name="Design" type="hidden" value="1" />
    <input type="submit" class="button" id="js-button" value="SELECT MINTMARK">
  </div>
</div>
</form>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Please show us the relevant code snippets. Thank you.

Comment: It's very difficult to tell without the HTML and JS code involved. But my first guess would be that clicking the label causes the form to be submitted before the input element is set. When you go back the input is set so clicking the label again will already have the correct value for the input.

Comment: Apologies for not including the code, I've added it to my main post now. You'll see that one radio button is already pre-selected. If one of the other 2 labels are clicked, the form always passess the incorrect value on the first submission. Hit the back button & re-click the label & the correct value is passed.

Answer (score 0):

first change

```
<form action="lookup.asp" method="post">
```

to

```
<form action="lookup.asp" method="post" name="test_form" id="test_form">
```

Second change

```
onClick="this.form.submit()"
```

to

```
onClick="document.forms.test_form.submit()"
```

EDIT: You can also do it like this

```
onclick="submit_form()"




<script>
function submit_form()
  {
     $("#test_form").submit();
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Hi @saswat, I've done what you've suggested but it doesn't seem to have worked. Do you have any other ideas what it might be?

Comment: No luck on that either. 

[link]http://goldsovereignexpert.com/year.asp?CoinDate=1874

Clicking the second image should take you to a page with 3 images of Queen Victoria. However it incorrectly submits & shows 2 images of shield design coins. Hit the back button & re-click & the form will submit correctly.

Is it something I've done wrong?